# Hash of nested (struct) data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, hash, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have the following data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType        

data = [
        (("James",None,"Smith"),"OH","M"),
        (("Anna","Rose",""),"NY","F"),
        (("Julia","","Williams"),"OH","F"),
        (("Maria","Anne","Jones"),"NY","M"),
        (("Jen","Mary","Brown"),"NY","M"),
        (("Mike","Mary","Williams"),"OH","M")
        ]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StructType([
         StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
         StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
         StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
         ])),
     StructField('state', StringType(), True),
     StructField('gender', StringType(), True)
     ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = schema)
```

with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
```

So the `name` column looks like this:

```
+----------------------+
|name                  |
+----------------------+
|[James,, Smith]       |
|[Anna, Rose, ]        |
|[Julia, , Williams]   |
|[Maria, Anne, Jones]  |
|[Jen, Mary, Brown]    |
|[Mike, Mary, Williams]|
+----------------------+
```

Is there an easy way to get the hash value of each of the rows in the `name` column? Or does hashing only work for unnested data?

Comment: Do you mean the hash value used internally by pyspark?

Comment: @alexpdev: something similar to from pyspark.sql.functions import md5, concat_ws
df_employee = df_employee.withColumn("md5", md5(concat_ws("", *col_list))) where col_list can be a single or multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a hash from the struct type column, you first need to convert the struct to e.g. string. [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json) does the job. After that you can use a hash function like `md5`.

```py
F.md5(F.to_json('name'))
```

Using your example df:

```py
df = df.withColumn('md5', F.md5(F.to_json('name')))
df.show(truncate=0)
# +----------------------+-----+------+--------------------------------+
# |name                  |state|gender|md5                             |
# +----------------------+-----+------+--------------------------------+
# |{James, null, Smith}  |OH   |M     |ad4f22b4a03070026957a65b3b8e5bf9|
# |{Anna, Rose, }        |NY   |F     |c8dcb8f6f52c2e382c33bd92819cd500|
# |{Julia, , Williams}   |OH   |F     |63a7c53d21f53e37b3724312b14a8e97|
# |{Maria, Anne, Jones}  |NY   |M     |a0f2d3962be4941828a2b6f4a02d0ac5|
# |{Jen, Mary, Brown}    |NY   |M     |cae64ee19dd2a0c9745a20e759a527e9|
# |{Mike, Mary, Williams}|OH   |M     |5e882c033be16bd679f450889e97be6d|
# +----------------------+-----+------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: What about Arrays within Structs?

Comment: It works well when structs contain arrays, as far as I can tell. Is there any specific issue that you see?

Comment: Not yet. So it should work for a Struct within an Array within an Array within an Array for example?

Comment: For the example given in your question, it works. In the first comment, you asked about another case, it still works. Now you thought of even another case, and I'm not even sure you understand that this case is different from the previous one. Please, update the question instead of putting all cases into comments. Questions on Stack Overflow should not be too broad, and it must be asked where the question is asked.