# Comparing md5 hash values in PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, hash

Suppose we have a dataframe `df` that looks like this (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73094684/hash-of-nested-struct-data/73105132?noredirect=1#comment129125156_73105132) question as a reference):

```py
# +----------------------+-----+------+--------------------------------+
# |name                  |state|gender|md5_hash_actual                 |
# +----------------------+-----+------+--------------------------------+
# |{James, null, Smith}  |OH   |M     |ad4f22b4a03070026957a65b3b8e5bf9|
# |{Anna, Rose, }        |NY   |F     |c8dcb8f6f52c2e382c33bd92819cd500|
# |{Julia, , Williams}   |OH   |F     |63a7c53d21f53e37b3724312b14a8e97|
# |{Maria, Anne, Jones}  |NY   |M     |a0f2d3962be4941828a2b6f4a02d0ac5|
# |{Jen, Mary, Brown}    |NY   |M     |cae64ee19dd2a0c9745a20e759a527e9|
# |{Mike, Mary, Williams}|OH   |M     |5e882c033be16bd679f450889e97be6d|
# +----------------------+-----+------+--------------------------------+
#
# root
#  |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- state: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- md5: string (nullable = true)
```

(Schema is important too, as field names are also included when creating the hash.)

This is how the hash is created:

```
df = df.withColumn('md5', F.md5(F.to_json('name')))
```

Now suppose that the names are supposed to be `{Alex, Jim, Henry}` for the first row and `{Anna, Rose, Katy}` in the second row. Is there an easy way to compare the `md5_hash_actual` with what the hash values are supposed to be? Would you have to create two new columns (`name_expected`, and `md5_hash_expected`) to compute and compare the hash values?

Is there a better way of doing this than having to add extra columns to the dataframe?

Comment: Where do those new values come from? Do you have a table with them? If so, you will need to have an ID column to join the tables first. It would be beneficial to give an example of that other table.

Comment: It's best to create the hash using the same method (from the same type column). So I would advice to put those new values in a column with of the same struct type and use the same algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these other names are stored in another table:

```py
data2 = [
        (1,("Alex","Jim","Henry")),
        (2,("Anna","Rose","Katy")),
        (3,("Julia","","Williams")),
        (4,("Maria","Anne","Jones")),
        (5,("Jen","Mary","Brown")),
        (6,("Mike","Mary","Williams"))
]

schema2 = StructType([    
    StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('name', StructType([
         StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
         StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
         StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
         ]))
    ]
)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2)
df2.show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|                name|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|  {Alex, Jim, Henry}|
|  2|  {Anna, Rose, Katy}|
|  3| {Julia, , Williams}|
|  4|{Maria, Anne, Jones}|
|  5|  {Jen, Mary, Brown}|
|  6|{Mike, Mary, Will...|
+---+--------------------+
```

Note that you have to have a unique column (like `id`) between the two dataframes to join on. Then these `ids` should be present in your original df too:

```
+---+--------------------+-----+------+--------------------+
| id|                name|state|gender|     md5_hash_actual|
+---+--------------------+-----+------+--------------------+
|  1|{James, null, Smith}|   OH|     M|ad4f22b4a03070026...|
|  2|      {Anna, Rose, }|   NY|     F|c8dcb8f6f52c2e382...|
|  3| {Julia, , Williams}|   OH|     F|63a7c53d21f53e37b...|
|  4|{Maria, Anne, Jones}|   NY|     M|a0f2d3962be494182...|
|  5|  {Jen, Mary, Brown}|   NY|     M|cae64ee19dd2a0c97...|
|  6|{Mike, Mary, Will...|   OH|     M|5e882c033be16bd67...|
+---+--------------------+-----+------+--------------------+
```

Now, there is no need to create another column in `df` to store the names. A join is required, and then we could do the comparison directly:

```py
df = df.join(df2, 'id', 'left') \
        .withColumn('md5_hash_match_on_name', F.when(df['md5_hash_actual']==F.md5(F.to_json(df2['name'])), True).otherwise(False))\
        .select(df['name'], df['state'], df['gender'], 'md5_hash_actual', 'md5_hash_match_on_name')
df.show()

+--------------------+-----+------+--------------------+----------------------+
|                name|state|gender|     md5_hash_actual|md5_hash_match_on_name|
+--------------------+-----+------+--------------------+----------------------+
|{James, null, Smith}|   OH|     M|ad4f22b4a03070026...|                 false|
|      {Anna, Rose, }|   NY|     F|c8dcb8f6f52c2e382...|                 false|
| {Julia, , Williams}|   OH|     F|63a7c53d21f53e37b...|                  true|
|{Maria, Anne, Jones}|   NY|     M|a0f2d3962be494182...|                  true|
|  {Jen, Mary, Brown}|   NY|     M|cae64ee19dd2a0c97...|                  true|
|{Mike, Mary, Will...|   OH|     M|5e882c033be16bd67...|                  true|
+--------------------+-----+------+--------------------+----------------------+
```